# CakePHP truncating large varchar columns from SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, cakephp

Using CakePHP 1.3.11 and SQL Server 2005 and the included MSSQL database driver.

I need to retrieve a `varchar(8000)` field, however the typical `find()` queries truncate this field to 256 characters; the actual array value array['comment'] is truncated, so the data beyond character 256 isn't accessed by my application at all.

I tried changing the field to a `text` datatype and with that change the query returns the full value of the column. Is there a way for cake to read the full value of the column or does it always truncate `varchars` to 256 characters?

Comment: it is truncated in a form input in the view? OR from the find results. (do the var_dump($this->data) or the find per se or the variable asscoiated with the find.

Comment: The actual value in the array is truncated, I should have been clear. The form shows the whole value if `text` datatype is used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution has been to use the `text` data type on the database side.